# Is there a way to get a list of types that i can use in Generic Methods?

Tags: c#

Hi so what I wanted is something along the lines of, is it possible in c#? ~

(and without using reflection?)

Current:

```
    protected override void AddTelegrams()
    {
         TelegramPublisher.Subscribe<Telegram1>(TelegramReceived);
         TelegramPublisher.Subscribe<Telegram2>(TelegramReceived);
         TelegramPublisher.Subscribe<Telegram3>(TelegramReceived);
    }

    protected override void RemoveTelegrams()
    {
         TelegramPublisher.UnSubscribe<Telegram1>(TelegramReceived);
         TelegramPublisher.UnSubscribe<Telegram2>(TelegramReceived);
         TelegramPublisher.UnSubscribe<Telegram3>(TelegramReceived);
    }
```

Objective:

```
    private IEnumerable<Type> GetListTelegramTypes()
    {
        return new List<Type>()
        {
            typeof(Telegram1),
            typeof(Telegram2),
            typeof(Telegram3)
        };
    }

    protected override void AddTelegrams()
    {
        foreach (var type in GetListTelegramTypes())
            TelegramPublisher.Subscribe<type>(TelegramReceived);
    }

    protected override void RemoveTelegrams()
    {
        foreach (var type in GetListTelegramTypes())
            TelegramPublisher.UnSubscribe<type>(TelegramReceived);
    }
```

Also Subscribe and Unsubscribe generic type mas be or inherit from "Telegram"...

Comment: What is wrong with reflection?

Comment: It's a bit unclear (to me) what you're asking. Can you expand to a real-life example so that we can see what it is you're having difficulty accomplishing?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why not register certain `ITelegramReceiver` types?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError and@Icepicle just add what I had and what I want, but canton7 delivered a perfect solution!

Comment: @mfabruno: Good for you (both) - I guess he's had more coffee than I had today ;)

Comment: Tea. The secret is lots of tea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use reflection, you can do something like:

```
public interface ITelegramSubscriber
{
    void Subscribe(TelegramReceivedHandler handler);
    void Unsubscribe(TelegramReceivedHandler handler);
}

public class TelegramSubscriber<T> : ITelegramSubscriber
{
    public void Subscribe(TelegramReceivedHandler handler) =>
        TelegramPublisher.Subscribe<T>(handler);
    public void Unsubscribe(TelegramReceivedHandler handler) =>
        TelegramPublisher.Unsubscribe<T>(handler);
}
```

Then:

```
private IEnumerable<ITelegramSubscriber> GetListTelegramSubscribers()
{
    return new List<ITelegramSubscriber>()
    {
        new TelegramSubscriber<Telegram1>(),
        new TelegramSubscriber<Telegram2>(),
        new TelegramSubscriber<Telegram3>(),
        new TelegramSubscriber<Telegram4>(),
    };
}

protected override void AddTelegrams()
{
    foreach (var subscriber in GetListTelegramSubscribers())
        subscriber.Subscribe(TelegramReceived);
}

protected override void RemoveTelegrams()
{
    foreach (var subscriber in GetListTelegramSubscribers())
        subscriber.Unsubscribe(TelegramReceived);
}
```

---

This assumes that you have one `TelegramReceivedHandler` method type which handles all telegrams. If you in fact have multiple overloads (it isn't clear from your question), then you probably want something like:

```
public interface ITelegramSubscriber
{
    void Subscribe();
    void Unsubscribe();
}

public class TelegramSubscriber<T> : ITelegramSubscriber
{
    private readonly TelegramReceivedHandler<T> handler;
    public TelegramSubscriber(TelegramReceivedHandler<T> handler) => this.handler = handler;
 
    public void Subscribe() => TelegramPublisher.Subscribe<T>(handler);
    public void Unsubscribe() => TelegramPublisher.Unsubscribe<T>(handler);
}
```

Then:

```
private IEnumerable<ITelegramSubscriber> GetListTelegramSubscribers()
{
    return new List<ITelegramSubscriber>()
    {
        new TelegramSubscriber<Telegram1>(TelegramReceived),
        new TelegramSubscriber<Telegram2>(TelegramReceived),
        new TelegramSubscriber<Telegram3>(TelegramReceived),
        new TelegramSubscriber<Telegram4>(TelegramReceived),
    };
}

protected override void AddTelegrams()
{
    foreach (var subscriber in GetListTelegramSubscribers())
        subscriber.Subscribe();
}

protected override void RemoveTelegrams()
{
    foreach (var subscriber in GetListTelegramSubscribers())
        subscriber.Unsubscribe();
}
```